# Why is this simple OpenCL code not vectorised?

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

The code below does not vectorise. With 'istart = n * 1;' instead of the 'istart = n * niters;' it does. With 'istart = n * 2;' it again does not.

```
// Kernel for ERIAS_critical_code.py

__kernel void pi(
   int                niters,   
   __global float*    A_d,
   __global float*    S_d,
   __global float*    B_d)                        
{                                                          
   int num_wrk_items  = get_local_size(0);                 
   int local_id       = get_local_id(0); // work item id                  
   int group_id       = get_group_id(0); // work group id                  

   float accum = 0.0f;                              
   int i, istart, iend, n;                                      

   n= group_id * num_wrk_items + local_id;

   istart = n * niters;
   iend   = istart + niters;

   for (i= istart; i< iend; i++){
       accum += A_d[i] * S_d[i];
} 

   B_d[n] = accum;

   barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE); // test: result is correct without this statement            
}
```

If the code cannot be vectorised I get:

Kernel  was not vectorized

If it can be:

Kernel  was successfully vectorized (8)

Any idea why it is not vectorised?

Answer (score 1):

When niters is 1, it makes the for loop cycle only once. This means every workitem computes its own element, in a coalesced access to memory.

Coalesced access is one of conditions to have N neighboring threads/workitems mapped to a SIMD hardware such as with width 8.

When niters is greater than 1, every workitem works only with strides of niters between neighboring workitems. This means SIMD hardware is useless. Only 1 memory cell per workitem is used at a time.

When niters is 2, at least only 2-fold memory bank collision happens. But with very big niters value, memory bank collisions happen more, making it very slow. Using SIMD or not doesn't matter (vectorized or not) as its performance will be locked into the serialized memory read/write latencies.

That for loop is doing a reduction serially. You should make it parallel. There are many examples out there, pick one and apply to your algorithm. For example, have each workitem compute a sum between id and id+niters/2 then reduce them on id and id+niters/4 and continue like this until at last only 1 workitem does final summation of id and id+1 elements.

If the reduction is a global version, then you can do local reduction per workgroup then apply their results same way on another kernel to do the global reduction.

Since you are making only partial sums per workitem, you could do "strided sum per workitem" such that each workitem using same for loop but leaping by M elements where M is something wont disturb the SIMD mapping on kernel workitems. Maybe M could be 1/100 of global number of elements(N) and for loop would cycle for 100 times (or N/M times). Something like this:

```
                time 1      time 2      time 3      time 4
workitem 1        0           15          30          45
workitem 2        1           16          31          46
workitem 3        2           17          32          47
 ...
workitem 15       14          29          44          59
               coalesced    coalesced   coalesced    coalesced
```

to complete 15 partial sums for 60 elements using 15 workitems. If SIMD length can fit this 15 workitems, it is good.

Lastly, the barrier operation is not needed since kernel ending is an implicit synchronization point globally for all workitems in it. Barrier only needed when you need to use those written results on another workitem in same kernel.